# normal sylow-p group in G is unique?

Tags: group-theory

I have a theoretical questions. Say $A \lt G$ a sylow-p group meaning $gcd([G:A],p)=1$ and $A\triangleleft G$ is it **necessarily** that $n_{p}(G)=1$, I obviously know the other way is true.

Comment: Yes. Google "Sylow theorems" ...perhaps Sylow's third theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate to each other by the second Sylow theorem. And normal subgroups have no conjugates except for themselves. Thus $n_p(G)=1$.

Side note: $\gcd([G:A], p)=1$ is always satisfied for Sylow $p$-subgroups (at least when $G$ is finite).

Comment: "And normal subgroups have no conjugates except for themselves. " didn't think of that - thanks!

Comment: @KimSeel Yeah, that's pretty straight forward. What is a conjugate of $A$? It's a subgroup of the form $hAh^{-1}$. But if $A$ is normal then $hAh^{-1}=A$.

Comment: Follow up question: say $|G|=p^\beta \cdot m$ where p is a prime and  $A \triangleleft G$ and we know A is of order $p^\alpha$ does it follow that $\alpha = \beta$ ?

Comment: @KimSeel Assuming $A$ is a Sylow subgroup? Then yes, this is exactly what the first Sylow theorem is about. $A$ doesn't have to be normal, it always holds.